# Muting only the second incoming call

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

I am able to mute an incoming call, but I would also like to block the sound you hear when you are already in a call and a second call comes in, is this possible?

This is what I use to mute a call:

```
final AudioManager am = ((AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE));
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                mOldStreamVolume = am.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
                am.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, AudioManager.ADJUST_MUTE, 0);
            } else {
                // deprecated since 22 or 23
                am.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, true);
            }
```